# Best way to store & retrieve immutable byte chunks in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra as a chunked object store.

I use a replication factor of 3.
I write chunks with CL_ONE, then, once the write completes, I read with CL_ONE.

Since chunks are immutable I dont have the risk of reading stale data.

However, I can run into a NotFoundException, because when trying to read a chunk just after writing one, all replicas may not have the chunk yet.

What I have tried to solve the problem :

- Retry the read in CL_ONE until the replicas have the chunk. This can take several seconds, if not minutes
- So now I try the read once with CL_ONE, and then if that fails, i retry with CL_ALL. Since I read only after the first write completes, I should get a response in all cases, at the expense of asking all the replicas for the chunk

My question is, is it this the best way (in terms of throughput, not reliability) to manage the reading/writing of immutable chunks in Cassandra?

Thanks in advance,

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

I am neither sure I understood what you're doing nor sure you are using Cassandra in the right way.

If your goal is to achieve consistency between a write and subsequent read then you have to respect the

Write CL + Read CL > RF

disequation. The most safe way to achieve it is using both quorum on write and read (quorum is 2 when RF=3 so 2+2>3) -- probably the fastest way is write in all and read in one.

Comment: I'm using the Netflix recipe for ChunkedObjectStore.
Of course I could use your disequation but then I would have a performance issue since I'm most of the time fetching the same chunks multiple times, since the chunks are immutable.

So I read/write with CL_ONE for maximum performance, and I just need to retry the read somehow in case of NOT Found errors, which will only happen when the chunks was just written and is not replicated yet.

I hope you understand my problem a bit better now?